# Button execution from Userform throwing Subscript out of Range error

Tags: excel, vba

Button for the code was previously present in the Excel Sheet, tested and executed successfully. Now I have shifted that button to a Userform, when executed I get an error

> subscript out of Range

When Step Debugging is used
error occurs at line 1

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).ClearContents
```

I cant figure out the fault.

```
Private Sub OUTCLR_Click()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).ClearContents
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).ClearContents
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 5).Value = "RESULT"
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = "PROCESSED UNIQUE STRINGS"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a worksheet named "Sheet1" in your workbook?

Comment: Are these 4 lines meant to work off the same worksheet? Why not use the `Sheet1` codename/identifier for all then?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here.

1. The implicit `Worksheets` collection is tied to whichever workbook is active when the code runs, and it may very well **not** be the workbook you expect. Another workbook does not necessarily contain a worksheet whose name, as seen from Excel on the worksheet's tab, is "Sheet1".
2. Assuming the expected workbook is active, `Worksheets("Sheet1")` will fail with "Subscript out of range" if none of its worksheets bears the name "Sheet1" as seen from Excel. Note that any given worksheet has both `Name` and `CodeName` properties. `Name` is as seen from Excel, and may change anytime. `CodeName` is as seen from the Visual Basic Editor, in the worksheet's properties under (Name). This name, which you can set to your liking, will remain stable over time. You can use it directly in code, as you did in the last 2 lines of your code.

If you intent is to manipulate the worksheet with CodeName Sheet1 in the workbook executing the code, directly use Sheet1 on your 4 lines of code; don't bother with the `Worksheets` collection.

Answer (score 1):

When the button was in a worksheet's code-behind, the `ActiveWorkbook` was guaranteed to be `ThisWorkbook`.

Now that it's in a UserForm, the `ActiveWorkbook` is whatever workbook happens to be active when the form is shown, and it can even change *while* the form is shown, depending on what code is in there.

Unqualified `Worksheets` calls are implicitly referring to `ActiveWorkbook`: it's like they're implicitly doing this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")...
```

Might work, but if the active workbook isn't what it's expected to be, **or** if somebody went and changed the tab/sheet name from `Sheet1` to `Summary 2018-12-21`, then it breaks: "subscript out of range" means whatever workbook is being queried, there's no sheet named "Sheet1" in it.

These on the other hand...

```
Sheet1.Cells(....)
```

Are using the worksheet's *code name* - which is independent of the user-modifiable tab name. The only way to tamper with these is to bring up the VBA editor, find the sheet in the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R), and change its `(Name)` property in the Properties toolwindow (F4).

If all 4 instructions mean to work off the same sheet and that sheet exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the file with the VBA code), make them all work off `Sheet1` - don't fetch that object from `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`, even less from `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: SO should notify contributors that "<user xyz> is working on an answer". Thanks for the upvote though ;-)